Isn't stacking suspend'able functions a performance killer?
While diving into Android/Kotlin development, I learned that the suspend keyword transforms the function into a state machine that can be removed from its executing thread, put on hold, and resumed at some time in the future, by either the same thread or another.
As I see it, a state machine brings some overhead in code, and execution time. Which of course is necessary and not really a problem.
However, in some existing code I am looking into, I find that some suspend function is calling other functions that suspend, like here:
Coroutine:
override suspend fun doWork() : <T> { calls A::methodA }
class A { suspend fun methodA() : <T> { calls B::methodB }
class B { suspend fun methodB() : <T> { performs some network I/O }

If I am right this would create three suspendable state machines. Woudln't it be better to have the suspendkeyword only at the doWork() Coroutine implementation? Or would I lose some threading flexibility (which I doubt) ?

"Woudln't it be better..." -- that depends a lot on your definition of "better", along with details of the roles of A and B and the actual work being done in those three functions.

Please note the time needed to perform the network I/O will be probably several orders of magnitude bigger than the overhead of calling, suspending and resuming all 3 functions. I never tried to benchmark the difference, but you are correct: I expect suspend functions introduce an overhead, which will be probably the worst if we call a very small function very frequently and it never suspends. In this case, it could be potentially just a regular function, but just because we marked it as suspend, it has to create some continuations, etc.

Or to make it simpler: if we write a very CPU-heavy algorithm, then most probably we don't use suspendable code as we never suspend. If we perform I/O or for any other reason we need to wait for something, then the overhead of suspend function is probably neglectable. Maybe the only "tricky" case is CPU-heavy algorithm, which uses coroutines for concurrency and do a lot of fork-joins, etc. In this case maybe the overhead of suspend functions will be a problem for us. But I'm making educated guesses here - again, I never run any benchmarks.
